# Can I do this with class objects?

Tags: c++, class

```
class xyz{

...
...
};

while(i<n){
           xyz ob;
           ...
           ...
}
```

Do I need to destroy the earlier object before reallocating memory to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You mean *define an object* not declare (removed from question).
2. Yes you can do that.
3. No you don't need to destroy it since it's destroyed automatically. The memory is allocated on the stack and will be reused anyway. The compiler can even optimize it in many cases. And **HOW** could you reallocate the memory anyway?

Answer (score 8):

No.

1. `ob` is a stack-allocated object, so its own lifecycle is managed automatically. It's constructed at the place where you declare it, destructed at `"}"`.
2. Since every `while` iteration is the separate `{ ... }` scope, the object will be constructed and destructed each iteration.

Answer (score 5):

Nope, its scope is limited to the while loop.

Answer (score 3):

No.  The scope of `ob` ends at the closing brace.  The compiler automatically calls the destructor on stack-based objects when they go out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

in each iteration, a completely new object is created. It just so happens they all have the same name xyz. In the end ob the iteration, the current object is destroyed via its destuctor, and in the next iteration a new object with the same name is created. So your code is perfectly fine. HTH